# How do I use the CakePHP Configure class?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to use the `Configure` class in CakePHP, but I'm not sure if I am using it correctly. I have read through the cook book and the API, but I can't seem to do what I want.

I have created a configuration file: *app/config/config.php*. I can directly edit this file and set variables in there and access them using `Configure::read()`.

Is it possible to update the values of the configuration file from the application itself, i.e., from a controller? I have tried using `Configure::write()`, but this does not seem to change the value.

Comment: Did you check the store method (http://api.cakephp.org/class/configure#method-Configurestore) of the Configure class?

Comment: I have seen the method, but I don't quite understand how it works. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: I am trying to create some custom configuration such as the the logo file as well as other settings. These settings should be changeable from the admin panel. I was originally going to store these details in the database, but this would result in querying the database on every page load, so I thought the Configure class would be more appropriate, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: It's used like `Configure::store("Test", "example_config", array("example" => "value"));`. This creates the file `example_config.php` in `app/tmp/cache/persistent/` with the content: `<?php $config = array(); $config['Test']['example'] = 'value';`. I'm not sure whether this is what you are looking for...

Comment: kind of, is there anyway this file could be stored in app/config? And is there any way to read from the file created?

Comment: No, the path is hardcoded in the Configure class. To read the file, you can use `Configure::load`.

Answer (score 1):

`app/config/config.php` isn't a file that's automatically loaded by Cake. Either move these variables into `app/config/bootstrap.php` or tell your `bootstrap.php` file to load your custom file. You could also put your variables in `app/config/core.php`, but I'd recommend against that. I tend to like leaving that file alone and adding/overwriting values in `bootstrap.php`.

Comment: The file is loaded in bootstrap.php, sorry I forgot to mention that. I can read values saved in my config.php file, but is it possible to change the value of the variables?

Comment: `Configure::write( 'name', 'value' )` should work if the file is loading properly.

Comment: @Rob `Configure::write` doesn't persist changes.

Comment: Do you mean persist within a request? If you need to persist across requests, you'll need to use the session. If you write the variable and then immediately read it, the value doesn't exist even then?

Comment: having played with configure::write, I can read the variable immediately after, but it is not stored in the config file, is there a way to store it in the file?

Comment: `Configure` doesn't persist anything between requests. You'll need to use the session for that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API](http://api.cakephp.org/class/configure), Configure is supposed to be used "for managing runtime configuration information".

You can use its methods to create, read, update and delete (CRUD) configuration variables at **runtime**. The Configure class is available everywhere in your CakePHP application and therefore CRUD operations performed on its data in any place, including a controller.

If you are looking for persistent storage, you could consider a database (SQL or NoSQL). I would not recommend using a text file, as it raises a lot of security concerns. Even if security is not an issue, a database is propably a more fitting solution.

More on the Configure class in the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/924/The-Configuration-Class).